# How, and why, can Foreign Key integrity errors occur in Django 3.0x?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to create a to-do list app in Django, and I want to link a user's profile to his own to-do list, to-do list items, and an additional deadline class.

I am currently trying to create my super user using createsuperuser. However, I am receiving an exception in that my Foreign Key Constraint has failed. Below is a traceback:

```
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 158, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 141, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 795, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 175, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/WebApp/users/signals.py", line 10, in create_profile
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 433, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 784, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 886, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 925, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1377, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Here is my **models.py** class:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import os
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
import datetime

class ToDoItem(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    item_desc = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_plural_name = "ToDoItems"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name


class ToDoList(models.Model):
    all_lists = models.TextField()

    item = models.ForeignKey(ToDoItem, default = 1, verbose_name = "ToDoItems",on_delete = models.SET_DEFAULT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ToDoLists"


    def __str__(self):
        return self.all_lists   

class Deadline(models.Model):
    deadline_heading = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    deadline_desc = models.TextField()
    deadline_due = models.DateTimeField("Date Due", default =datetime.date.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=7))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Deadlines"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.deadline_heading

class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    dl = models.ForeignKey(Deadline, default = 1, verbose_name = "Deadlines", on_delete = models.SET_DEFAULT)

    col_list = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, default = 1, verbose_name = "ToDoLists", on_delete = models.SET_DEFAULT)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

I understand that there is some discrepancy between my code and the database. However, I am unable to pinpoint exactly what the problem is. Can someone please point out my mistake?

I would also like to know how to overcome this problem, and what I can do to avoid such a problem in the future. Any suggestions?

I appreciate your help very much. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error happens here:

```
File "/Users/ganesh/dev/WebApp/WebApp/users/signals.py", line 10, in   create_profile
Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Probably it`s because either Deadline with id=1  or ToDoList with id=1 are referencing instances that don't exist in the related database table.
You can make sure that you created them in database.

Also you can remove default values from fields definitions and add null=True:

```
dl = models.ForeignKey(Deadline, null=True, verbose_name = "Deadlines", on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
col_list = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, null=True, verbose_name = "ToDoLists", on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Yes! It worked. I guess I had to forgo setting a default value, but I guess that's really optional. Thanks a lot for your help, @HelenShy!